Base64 Not encoding/decoding correctly
I have a website called Pastebin, that is a minimalistic version of the original Pastebin, but I am having trouble pasting code. My server won't accept it.
I tried encoding it in base64 which worked, and stored the data as base 64, and when I went to decode it through a tool it decoded perfectly, but when I view it at the generated pastebin link it displays like �������Y� ��T��T��ԑTUQT and I can't figure it out. I has a mostly working version that encoded and decoded perfectly but it wasn't just displaying the code, but displaying it with the html in it. So if I had <h1>Test</h1> in my code, it would display it as a header and not the plain code. I tried to find this again but it got lose in my revisions. Below I have my current (not working) code that has base64 encoding/decoding/displaying errors, I cant figure out which.
JS
    window.onload = function() {
        document.querySelector('#pasteForm').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var textArea = document.querySelector('#textToPaste');
            var formData = new FormData(e.target);

            var text = formData.get('text').replace(/\n/g, '<br>').replace(/^ /gm, '&nbsp;').replace(/^\t/gm, '&emsp;');
            var encodedText = btoa(text); // Encode the text in base64
            formData.set('text', '<pre>' + encodedText + '</pre>'); // Use the encoded text

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', 'create.php', true);

            xhr.onload = function() {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    var password = formData.get('password');
                    if (password) {
                        document.querySelector('#linkBox').value = xhr.responseURL + '?password=' + encodeURIComponent(password);
                    } else {
                        document.querySelector('#linkBox').value = xhr.responseURL;
                    }
                    document.querySelector('#overlay').style.display = 'block';
                    document.querySelector('#popup').style.display = 'block';
                } else {
                    console.error('An error occurred');
                }
            };

            xhr.send(formData);
        });

        document.querySelector('#closeButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
            document.querySelector('#overlay').style.display = 'none';
            document.querySelector('#popup').style.display = 'none';
        });

        document.querySelector('#copyButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
            var linkBox = document.querySelector('#linkBox');
            linkBox.select();
            document.execCommand('copy');

            var copyButtonIcon = document.querySelector('#copyButton img');
            var originalIconSrc = copyButtonIcon.src;
            copyButtonIcon.src = 'https://cdn.cirrus.center/main/icons/check.png';

            setTimeout(function() {
                copyButtonIcon.src = originalIconSrc;
            }, 2000);
        });
    };

PHP
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    if (!file_exists('paste')) {
        mkdir('paste');

        $redirectIndex = '<?php' . PHP_EOL;
        $redirectIndex .= 'header("Location: ..");' . PHP_EOL;
        $redirectIndex .= 'exit;' . PHP_EOL;
        file_put_contents('paste/index.php', $redirectIndex);
    }

    $dir = uniqid();
    mkdir("paste/$dir");

    $decodedText = '';
    if (isset($_POST['text']) && $_POST['text'] !== '') {
        $decodedText = base64_decode($_POST['text']); // Decode the base64 text
        $decodedText = mb_convert_encoding($decodedText, 'UTF-8', 'auto'); // Convert the encoding to UTF-8
    }

    $index = '<?php' . PHP_EOL;

    if (isset($_POST['password']) && $_POST['password'] !== '') {
        $index .= 'if (!isset($_GET["password"]) || $_GET["password"] !== "' . $_POST['password'] . '") {' . PHP_EOL;
        $index .= '    echo "<h1>Incorrect password</h1>";' . PHP_EOL;
        $index .= '    exit;' . PHP_EOL;
        $index .= '}' . PHP_EOL;
    }

    $index .= 'echo <<<EOT' . PHP_EOL; // Use the decoded text
    $index .= $decodedText . PHP_EOL;
    $index .= 'EOT;' . PHP_EOL;

    if (isset($_POST['burn'])) {
        $index .= 'file_put_contents(__FILE__, "<h1>This paste has been deleted</h1>");' . PHP_EOL;
        $index .= 'exit;' . PHP_EOL;
    }

    $index .= '?>' . PHP_EOL;

    $index .= '<!DOCTYPE html>' . PHP_EOL;
    $index .= '<html>' . PHP_EOL;
    $index .= '<head>' . PHP_EOL;
    $index .= '    <title>' . ($_POST['title'] ?? 'Pastebin') . '</title>' . PHP_EOL;
    $index .= '</head>' . PHP_EOL;
    $index .= '<body>' . PHP_EOL;
    $index .= '' . PHP_EOL;
    $index .= '</body>' . PHP_EOL;
    $index .= '</html>';

    file_put_contents("paste/$dir/index.php", $index);

    header("Location: /paste/$dir");
    echo "/paste/$dir";
}


I'm not clear on your reason for base64 encoding, but maybe I'm missing something. I don't see any advantage in doing it. Also, unrelated, but I rarely see a good usage of mb_convert_encoding and I don't think this is one either.

People have left feedback that when they paste code, they get a 418 error (weird because 418 was added as an april fools joke, so my guess is that it is trying to prevent people from executing malicious code on the server) but storing it as base64 will resolve that error. The only issue I'm having is getting it to display properly

Okay, that makes sense, thanks for clarifying. I'm trying to follow your logic, but still am a little confused. In JS you are considering anything that isn't a 200 status to be an error, but in PHP you are calling header() with the Location directive which defaults to 302. Also, when you manually inspect the generated PHP, does it look correct? And I'm ignoring the rendered output, and focusing on the server-side portion only.

Also, you are allowing public submission of text that is interpreted as pure PHP, and it is very easy to exploit. See the file that starts with 663e for an example. Have you considered the security ramifications of this? Does it need to be executed? Can it just be written to the file system?

For your first response, I have only gotten 200 and 418. I guess then yes, so far anything other than 200 is an error, but again, it has been limited to 418. Yes the general PHP looks correct. It works for everything except code.
For your second response, I have actually, that was one of the main things I thought about making it.

Did you see my sample and what I did? Also, fighting this in JS is probably not a good idea because evil people will just bypass the JS and POST directly.

I didnt see your sample, but the code isn't executable.

That's good, so the code sample above needs to be updated? Because I definitely got phpinfo() to run previously. Also, make sure to guard the title, too, because I can get PHP to execute there.

And... while I'm in here, also guard your password which is allowing PHP, too. I just got phpinfo() to work again. Linux baroness-blood 5.4.32-grsec-grsec-plus+ #1 SMP Sat Apr 18 03:13:45 UTC 2020 x86_64

JavaScript strings are stored in UTF-16. To get UTF-8, you'll have to convert the string yourself, e.g. as in https://ecmanaut.blogspot.com/2006/07/encoding-decoding-utf8-in-javascript.html . Try var encodedText = btoa( unescape( encodeURIComponent( text)));

Noted, thanks. Will implement these for my next commit.

@CaelenCater, just a warning, using htmlspecialchars as your code is currently doing now is still not sufficient enough. All three fields are still exploitable. I'd actually recommend writing the raw text to a dedicated file and calling file_get_contents on that with an echo. For the password, use OpenSSL or Sodium to encrypt the payload, don't store the password. If decryption fails, then show "invalid password".

I'll look into this a little more, but some things might not be possible with my shared server. Thanks for all your feedback!

Here is what I am seeing, try it and let me know. I can revise this answer as needed.
In the javascript you seem to be passing a form field like so:
formData.set('text', '<pre>' + encodedText + '</pre>'); // Use the encoded text

Then it makes a form post to the server side PHP code and the form field 'text' is decoded like so:
$decodedText = base64_decode($_POST['text']); // Decode the base64 text
$decodedText = mb_convert_encoding($decodedText, 'UTF-8', 'auto'); // Convert the encoding to UTF-8

So a few potential issues here:
1-I think you need to remove the 'pre' tags when encoding, so:
formData.set('text', encodedText); // Use the encoded text

You can put the 'pre' tags in the PHP so the text renders properly:
$index .= '<pre>' . $decodedText . '</pre>' . PHP_EOL;

2-On javascript side you use btoa, but on PHP side you use base64_decode. These two commands could perhaps be incompatible, so you can use a tool to verify that PHP base64_decode is decoding the javascript btoa properly. You do mention using a tool to verify, but there can be cases where it sometimes decodes properly and sometimes does not, due to subtle incompatibility issues, so it's good to keep this in mind.
3-Not sure there is any need to use mb_convert_encoding. Try removing it.
Let me know what works for you.
*** Update:
See comments. The Pre tags in the javascript were causing the garbled text, they simply needed to be removed. After that, the server was generating an error 418 because it was flagging the PHP line that's doing the decoding, detecting a security vulnerability. They are following up with their server provider to resolve that part.

I think it needs to be stored in the end file as base64 because otherwise I get a 418 "I am a teapot" error. Thanks for taking time to help me with this!

The issue here though is that base64 should be a perfectly fine encoding to use in form posts and even in url query parameters, so not sure why the server would generate such a bizarre error. I would look for a different reason for the 418. If you simply remove those tags and do nothing else, will it then generate the error? The issue I see with putting pre tags in the field is then I would think it will try to base 64 decode the tag text along with the encoded text, and thus it will always decode wrong.

I don't know exactly what the error is. From what I can tell, when I make a paste without any of this additional encoding, it just returns a 418 error no matter what kind of code it was. When I started pasting it wrapped in pre tags and encoded in base 64 it would let me paste most types of code, and then the only problem was displaying it correctly so it would be decoded and displayed when loaded. With the changes you suggested, it will return a 418 error when I paste code (even in base64) and store it as plain text. The full code is on github if you want to experiment a little.

Ok thanks. I will just take your snippets and setup my own little sandbox and see what I can get to work. I will let you know what I find a little later today

I was able to duplicate your issue with the garbled text. It is indeed the Pre tags. Get rid of them out of the javascript and it should decode properly on the other end. As mentioned, you can put the Pre tags on the PHP end so that html text submitted in the box renders as raw html tags in the output. base64_decode and btoa had no issues in my tests, so that's probably not an issue. mb_convert_encoding seems not needed nor did it hurt when I tried with and without. So try making the Pre tag changes as I suggest here and let's go from there.

It didn't change much, I still get the 418 error when pasting code.

Yes, but now we can focus on the 418. The garbed text is caused by the Pre tags, so now let's work on that 418. Are you able to see exactly at what point the 418 happens?

One thing you can do is modify your stuff temporarily to just use an alert statement to dump the reult right back to the screen when you click the Submit button. I did it like below. If you get that to work, then simply start reworking the other code back in slowly and you will see exactly where the error gets generated.

Insert this after the xhr.open call to just display results simply, and modify php to just print the data back. This will help to see better what's causing error.
xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
alert(xhr.response);
}
};

It didn't give me any valuable information, but I did find this in my error log: [Fri May 10 12:55:34.551050 2024] [:error] [client 185.246.209.56:49102] [client 185.246.209.56] ModSecurity: Access denied with code 418 (phase 2). Matched phrase "base64_decode" at ARGS:text. [file "/etc/modsecurity/mod_sec3_CRS/99_dreamhost_rules.conf"] [line "126"] [id "1990070"] [msg "Common known arguments for backdoor shell present in ARGS:text"] [hostname "paste-bin.us"] [uri "/create.php"], referer: https://paste-bin.us/

Ah ha! So it's your server provider scanning your code and seems to be flagging this line:         $decodedText = base64_decode($_POST['text']);     Try taking the _POST reference out of that line and use a variable instead and pass the variable, ie,         $formVar = $_POST['text'], and $decodedText = base64_decode($formVar);   You may need to contact your server admin to resolve this.

Here is a link where it seems others are experiencing same issue: https://securitycheck.protegetuordenador.com/forum/9-newbies-area/1644-when-using-iframe-the-webmaster-has-forbidden-your-access-to-this-site

I also highly recommend that after you understand what's breaking your current code, that you modify it according to the advice of other people commenting, to address security and best practice concerns
